# SortedSet<T> vs HashSet<T>

Tags: c#, .net, collections, generics

My question is that what is the need of `HashSet<T>` when we have `SortedSet<T>`! All HashSet's methods are available in SortedSet too, moreover SortedSet is advantageous as it provides collection already in sorted manner! Even then HashSet is present. For what is it useful then?

Comment: HashSet<T> if you want items to be unsorted and unique? From MSDN > The HashSet<T> class provides
> high-performance set operations. A set
> is a collection that contains no
> duplicate elements, and whose elements
> are in no particular order. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Comment: What if you have a set of things that do not have a well-ordering in the first place? How would you make a *sorted* set of points in three-space, for example? What would you sort on?

Comment: A useful (sometimes) thing to know when working with `HashSet<T>`: even in 64-bit applications it can store up to ~48 millions of `Guid`s or `long`s or ~95 millions of `int`s, and throws `OutOfMemoryException` after that. `SortedSet<T>` seems to have a much higher capacity limit. If for some reason you need to keep hundreds of millions of items in memory, `HashSet<T>` might be not a good choice.

Comment: @Vladimir: According to the documentation, "For very large HashSet<T> objects, you can increase the maximum capacity to 2 billion elements on a 64-bit system by setting the enabled attribute of the <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects> configuration element to true in the run-time environment."

Answer (score 83, accepted):

If you don't need sorting, you shouldn't use a class that does sorting because that means your application will be doing more work than it needs to.  (It will make your app faster, in other words).

Comment: More importantly, the algorithm will run faster. Hashing is O(1), whereas the sorted set is likely using a binary search tree, which is O(log n) in the average case -- far worse performance.

Comment: In that case we can use List<T>, isn't it! Why need HashSet<T>??

Comment: Set are for unique items, List may contain duplicate entries. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx for the HashSet<T> documentation. It says: A set is a collection that contains _no duplicate elements_, and whose elements are in no particular order.

Comment: Please tell me one more thing... what does O(1) mean? I know it's a silly question, but seriously I have no idea what it is!

Comment: It's a rough indicator of the computational intensity of an algorithm.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @Novice: In layman's terms, an algorithm running in `O(1)` means that it runs in the same amount of time regardless the size of the input.  Otherwise, the time is dependent on the size of the input `n` and is expressed as a function of `n`.  e.g., linear: `O(n)`, quadratic: `O(n^2)`, etc.  The big-O wiki page can be a tough read, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) one summarizes it well I think.

Comment: FYI, the documentation for SortedSet appears to be inconsistent.  My local help says that SortedSet(Of T).Contains runs in O(1) time, while MSDN online says it runs in O(ln n) time.  HashSet, however, runs in O(1) time in both versions of the documentation.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN, the online version (MSDN) was obviously fixed compared to your older, wrong version. A `SortedSet<>` performs lookups in O(log n) time, a `HashSet<>` in O(1) time, and a `List<>` in O(n) time.

Comment: This is correct if your primary concern is speed but if your primary concern is memory, like say you are going to have a collection of many sets, a sortedset will all things being equal tend to use less space than a hash set because a sorted set is (presumably) a binary search tree while a hash set is a hash table that needs to be initiazed with some capacity with probably a heuristically determined amount of room to grow.

Comment: @jwezorek A tree based implementation requires an additional object and reference for every single item in the collection.  If the collection is of reference types (a common situation) then the collection uses more than twice as much memory as an array would.  Hashsets are going to be about that bad *in the worse case*, and won't be nearly as bad in the average case.

Answer (score 57):

This is about choosing the right tool for the job. Depends on the way you are going to use your collection.

[This page](https://web.archive.org/web/20130708052722/http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx) has a nice table detailing the differences between various collection classes.

Below is an extract from that table concerning the collections you are asking about:

| Collection | Ordering | Contiguous? | Direct Access? | Lookup | Manipulate | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HashSet | Unordered | Yes | Via Key | Key: O(1) | O(1) | Unique unordered collection, like a Dictionary except key and value are same object. |
| SortedSet | Sorted | No | Via Key | Key: O(log n) | O(log n) | Unique sorted collection, like SortedDictionary except key and value are same object. |

Note:

- **Contiguous?** means Contiguous *Storage*?
- **Lookup** means Lookup *Efficiency*
- and **Manipulate** means Manipulate *Efficiency*

Comment: I saw the article you linked to lists the Hashtable-based types (`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` and `HashSet<T>`) as "contiguous" - but they don't store their keys contiguously in their internal (i.e. often sparse) key arrays, whereas `SortedDictionary` and `SortedSet` use a dense tree, so I'm surprised the article doesn't touch on the memory usage of SortedSet vs HashSet for differing numbers of keys.

Comment: @Svisstack It is not appropriate to edit answers on this question as you have been.  If you feel the answer is incorrect, feel free to post you own answer that provides the facts you feel are accurate (or a comment explaining why you feel the author ought to change it).  Additionally, this answer is quoting another source, changing the content is now *claiming that another source is saying something that it is not*, which is *super* bad.  Your edit is also just factually wrong, but that's simply moot; it's not an appropriate edit anyway.

Comment: @Servy: it's not factually wrong, if you think that you can lookup on the HashSet in the O(1) then you are crazy, please read more about the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @Svisstack Technically lookup in a hashset is O(m) where m is the average hash collision rate of your hash function.  For a perfectly evenly distributed hash function, that results in the lookup being O(1), for a perfectly bad hash function that always collides, that'd make the lookup O(n) where n is the size of the set.  You generally only use a hash set with types that can have a good hash function, making it O(1) in most practical situations.  What makes you think it's O(log(n))?

Comment: @Svisstack https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

Comment: @Servy: You can't assume that your hash function is good and you have a limit set of data and preventing collisions in the big-o calculation. If you have a collision then you basically have Set and this is why you have log(n). If you are claiming constant on the lookup then this is the BEST CASE not the Big-O as in the Big-O you are assuming that the data approching infinity (it's the mathematical limit). Hashing completely doesn't matter in limit as the hash function and table size have constant size https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @Svisstack "You can't assume that your hash function is good"  Well, you *can*.  And most everyone does.  If you can't properly hash the object *you shouldn't be using it in a hash based collection*.  Some people will put an asterisk on that notation to indicate it assumes a good hash, because you're right it *is* an assumption made when stating O(1), even when it's a valid assumption.  "If you have a collision then you basically have Set "  No, then you have a list.  Searching through it requires a linear search, which is O(m) where m is the number of items in that hash bucket.

Comment: @Svisstack *Very* few data structures are designed in such a way that they will work properly, or even at all, when the number of items exceeds int.MaxValue.  Saying that if you have much, much more than int.MaxValue items operations are no longer O(1) is pretty meaningless as it's just not a supported use case from the start, so it's not a useful point to consider.  Things like `HashSet`, `List`, and `Dictionary` and so on will literally just break because arrays aren't allowed to be that big and they're all backed by a large array.

Comment: @Svisstack "If we would like in the world like that, put into hashset one item and you will have the same the contains time as if you will put max random items into the same hashset."   Yes.  **That is absolutely true** assuming the item has a well defined hashing function.  That's why hash sets are so useful.  Checking if an item is in the set *requires about the same amount of time regardless of the number of items in the set*.  It has restrictions on when you can do that (the item needs to be efficiently hashable), but that's a condition that's often achievable.

Answer (score 30):

Both **`HashSet<T>`** and **`SortedSet<T>`** are implementing [`interface ISet<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iset-1) which is a data structure holding unique elements.

The main difference between them is the underlying data structure they use to store data.
`HashSet<T>` uses a **hash-table** while `SortedSet<T>` uses a **red-black tree** which is a balanced binary tree.

The `HashSet<T>` which uses a hash table does the basic operations (i.e. Add, Remove, Search) faster than `SortedSet<T>` as the complexity of `HashSet<T>` is O(1) meaning it will do basic operations independent of the size of input data in a constant period of time while the complexity of `SortedSet<T>` is log(N) meaning depend on the size of input it will do the basic operations logarithmic. for example if the size of your input data is 1,000 then then the program does the basic operations in 10 steps and if it is 1,000,000 the program does the basic operations in 20 steps.

Conclusion: Use `HashSet<T>` **if you don't need the elements to be sorted** otherwise use `SortedSet<T>`. It means Using `HashSet<T>` is **preferable** unless you need sorting.

Comment: This is the best answer under this question. Very informational, thanks for sharing.